# How to fix attribute error for Metpy data from a netcdf file involving xarray

Tags: python-xarray, metpy

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'metpy'
```

when I am running my code. The particular lines in particular are:

```
import Scientific.IO.NetCDF as S
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import metpy
# Any import of metpy will activate the accessors
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
#from metpy.testing import get_test_data
from metpy.units import units
# Open the netCDF file as a xarray Datase


#
datadir='C:/Users/stratusshow/AppData/Local/lxss/home/stratus/PROJECT/NEWPROJECT/FEB012017/nam_218_20170131_1200_000.nc'
data = xr.open_dataset(datadir,decode_cf=True)
# To parse the full dataset, we can call parse_cf without an argument, and assign the returned
# Dataset.
```

***data = data.metpy.parse_cf()***

```
# If we instead want just a single variable, we can pass that variable name to parse_cf and
# it will return just that data variable as a DataArray.
data_var = data.metpy.parse_cf('Temperature_isobaric')
```

The line in bold is where the attribute error is popping up on. I am trying to learn how to use netcdf in metpy for some independent research as well as to learn metpy in general for future projects.

Comment: Would you be able to share which installed versions of MetPy and xarray you have, along with your Python version? I am unable to replicate this issue with Python 3.7 and the latest versions of MetPy and xarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is an out-of-date MetPy version. The Xarray accessor was added in v0.8. To update to the current version of MetPy with the latest functionality, you can upgrade with `conda update metpy` or `pip install --upgrade metpy`.