# NetCDF Attribute not found when using metpy and siphon to get data

Tags: python, metpy

I'm trying to plot some meteorological data in NetCDF format accessed via the Unidata siphon package.

I've imported what the MetPy docs suggest are the relevant libraries

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import num2date
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
from datetime import datetime

import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.units import units
```

and I've constructed a query for data as per the Siphon docs

```
best_gfs = TDSCatalog('http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/grib/NCEP/GFS/Global_0p25deg/catalog.xml?dataset=grib/NCEP/GFS/Global_0p25deg/Best')

best_ds = best_gfs.datasets[0]
ncss = best_ds.subset()
query = ncss.query()
query.lonlat_box(north=55, south=20, east=-60, west=-90).time(datetime.utcnow())
query.accept('netcdf4')
query.variables('Vertical_velocity_pressure_isobaric','Relative_humidity_isobaric','Temperature_isobaric','u-component_of_wind_isobaric','v-component_of_wind_isobaric','Geopotential_height_isobaric')

data = ncss.get_data(query)
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to parse the dataset using the code from the Metpy docs

```
data = data.metpy.parse_cf()
```

I get an error: "AttributeError: NetCDF: Attribute not found"

When attempting to fix this problem, I came across [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58045079/how-to-fix-attribute-error-for-metpy-data-from-a-netcdf-file-involving-xarray)  that seems to have the same issue, but the solution suggested there --  to update my metpy to the latest version, -- did not work for me. I updated metpy using Conda but got the same problem as before I updated. Any other ideas on how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the following code in Siphon

```
data = ncss.get_data(query)
```

will return a `Dataset` object from `netcdf4-python`. You need one extra step to hand this to xarray, which will make MetPy's `parse_cf` available:

```
from xarray.backends import NetCDF4DataStore
ds = xr.open_dataset(NetCDF4DataStore(data))
data = ds.metpy.parse_cf()
```